# Program won't let the user input the number of rows in Pascal's triangle - Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, computer-science

I want the user to be able to tell the program how many rows they want from the Pascals triangle but my code throws back an error saying- "array dimension missing'
This the task- "Your job is to create the first few rows of Pascal’s triangle in a multidimensional array and then output it to the screen"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class PascalsTriangle
{
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount of rows you want to 
        be shown: ");
        int tri = sc.nextInt();

        int [][] triangle = new int[][];

        for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++)
        {
            triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
            triangle[i][0] = 1;
            triangle[i][i] = 1;

            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
            {
                triangle[i][j] = triangle[i - 1][j]+triangle[i - 1][j - 
                1];
            }
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++)
            { 
                System.out.print(" "+triangle[i][j]);
            }
                System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: int [][] triangle = new int[][];, your array must have a size.

Comment: `int [][] triangle = new int[][];` isn't legal.  Like the error message says, you have to pick a size when you create an array.

Comment: What can I change to be able to have users input the amount of rows instead of me picking the size?

Comment: You set the variable `tri` with the user input but you don't use it. Using this information and the one in the other comments, I'm sure you can figure out what to do

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have said -- the problem isn't with your user input, it's with your initialization of the array.

```
int [][] triangle = new int[][];
```

Should probably be something like:

```
int [][] triangle = new int[tri][tri * 2];
```